# Aggregation Framework Sort by Date issues with blanks

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework

I am using the Aggregation Framework in MongoDB to sort a result set by a date field. The sort is working perfectly with the exception of the records with blank dates in the sort field. How can I move these blanks to the end of the sorted result collection while maintaining my earliest to latest sort order for the ones with dates?

```
query.where('state','published').sort('startDate');
```

Answer (score 0):

Let say I have the following documents in my collection:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55669d58d70a9b1a45e11ed5"), "state" : "published", "startDate" : "Thu May 28 2015 07:45:12 GMT+0300" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55669d62d70a9b1a45e11ed6"), "state" : "published", "startDate" : "     " }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55669d67d70a9b1a45e11ed7"), "state" : "published", "startDate" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55669d6ad70a9b1a45e11ed8"), "state" : "published", "startDate" : "Thu May 28 2015 07:45:30 GMT+0300" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55669ec4d70a9b1a45e11ed9"), "state" : "published" }
```

You can filter documents with blank date using [**`$regex`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

```js
db.test.aggregate([{"$match": {"state": "published", "startDate": /\S+/}}, {$sort: {"startDate": 1}}])
```

Output:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55669d58d70a9b1a45e11ed5"), "state" : "published", "startDate" : "Thu May 28 2015 07:45:12 GMT+0300" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55669d6ad70a9b1a45e11ed8"), "state" : "published", "startDate" : "Thu May 28 2015 07:45:30 GMT+0300" }
```

EDIT:

If you sort your document by `startDate` in descending order  you get the expected result.

```js
db.test.aggregate(
    [
        { "$match": { "state": "published" }}, 
        { $sort: { "startDate": -1 }}
    ]
)
```

Comment: But I still need to output the documents with blank startDates, just at the end of the output collection.

Comment: Thanks @Michael but the data I am working with is future dates (sorting in decending order places the furthest future occurring event in the first position).

Comment: @JRulle you can't sort your data in ascending order and have data with blanks date at the end. you will need to  filter document with blank date in your query or write two queries and merge the result.

Comment: I am actually working on using $project to create a new field for each document that simply categorizes the documents as dates and nodates. From that point I will sort first on the dates/nodates category field then on the startDate field.